# How to include parent directory include path in Android.mk?

Tags: c, android-ndk, porting, include-path, android.mk

I'm building using the NDK and am having trouble getting the parent directory in the include path.  I tried this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/..
```

But that does not work, apparently the `..` is not processed as I would expect.  I ran `make -n` to see the generated command which includes what I want:

```
-I/Users/me/android/workspace/jni/module/popt/..
```

But it fails, although if I manually edit it to instead be:

```
-I/Users/me/android/workspace/jni/module
```

It works fine.  What should I put in the `Android.mk` file to include the parent directory in the search path without using `..`?

The issue is that `popt` is a symbolic link, so parent directory `..` is not `module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be expanding the `..` and actually modifying the earlier parts of the path - this is pretty much the same in any build system if you specify a relative path with `..`.

Why doesn't `-I/Users/me/android/workspace/jni/module/popt/..` give the same result as `-I/Users/me/android/workspace/jni/module`? Is `popt` a symlink to a different place? In that case, I think a solution would be to define a separate variable in `jni/module/Android.mk` like `MODULE_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)` and use `$(MODULE_PATH)` instead of `$(LOCAL_PATH)/..` in the other `Android.mk` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "wildcard", for example:

```
PARENT_DIR_PATH := $(wildcard ..)
```